# fabric.js guideline with ruler

Tags: javascript, reactjs, canvas, html5-canvas, fabricjs

I created a ruler with guideline, and this guideline can moved vertically and horizontally depends if the line is in vertical or horizontal way. If we add another objects and create a selection of many object and one of this lines are in this selection the guideline working incorrectly.

What I want is if this line in group selection stay fix (selectable) and if I select as single work normally and can move it

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: The below question is to find a logic for that using fabric js